# No resource found when clicking on "Application settings" in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Service that is happily running in Azure and has been running for quite a while. Yesterday I went to the "Application settings" for the app service, in the Azure Portal, and I am met with the error:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

This has only recently started to happen. Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed at Azure Support. There is most likely nothing that you have done to cause this, nor is there anything that you can do to fix it.

Comment: It may well be a problem with the app though, potentially it is related to an invalid web.config for example (a bit of Googling about would suggest this as a possibility, although I can't see anything wrong with mine at the moment). It would be good to know if anyone else has seen this problem and it has been due to a code/config issue.

Comment: Either way the app was redeployment overnight and now the settings are back. So whether there was a corrupt file somewhere or the deployment prompted Azure to correct the issue, I don't know, but it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you have hosted your web site in East US region, refer the below.

This could be possibly due to the Service Interruption starting at 08:02 UTC on 24 Jan 2018 a subset of customers using App Service \ Web Apps in East US who may experience intermittent latency, timeouts or HTTP 500-level response codes while performing service management operations such as site create / delete and moving resources on App Service deployments. Autoscaling and loading site metrics may also be impacted. Engineers continue to investigate to isolate the underlying cause. The next update will be provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant.

For more details, refer this page: [Azure status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/status/)

Also, try to clear cache/cookies/temp files and re-login to the Azure Portal and then check.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, my issue started yesterday and is hosted in UK South, so I don't think this could be the issue with my app.

Comment: Try clearing browser cookies/cache or InPrivate mode and see if that helps to resolve the issue. If issue persists, Please contact Azure support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request for further assistance.

Comment: A redeployment fixed the issue, thanks for the suggestions.